# Online diff tool that can visualise differences between two texts by only using a url

Tags: text, diff

Is there a website that can show the difference between two texts and I can somehow pass arguments to the URL that contain each of the texts? If there is a concern about long parameters then using something to compact/compress the two texts before giving as arguments to the URL would be fine.

So an example of usage is:

http://awesomedifftool.com/compare.do?text1=comparethistext?text2=withthattext

and so when I click on the above link it would show me the differences in nicely formatted text with colour highlighting between texts:

**comparethistext**

and

**withthattext**

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with process substitution in GNU Bash, plus GNU diff, and the wget utility:

```
$ diff -u <(wget -O - http://example.com/foo) <(wget -O - http://example.com/bar)
```

Concrete example. What is the difference between amazon.com and amazon.ca, ignoring whitespace?

```
$ diff -ub <(wget -O - http://amazon.com) <(wget -O - http://amazon.ca)
```

Partial output:

```
--- /dev/fd/63  2013-06-10 15:50:59.919468076 -0700
+++ /dev/fd/62  2013-06-10 15:50:59.923468026 -0700
@@ -9,11 +9,6 @@



-
-
-  
-
-
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

@@ -35,7 +30,7 @@
   <script type="text/javascript">

   var btiplv;
-     new Image().src = "http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/gno/beacon/BeaconSprite-US-01._V397411194_.png";
+     new Image().src = "http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/15/gno/beacon/BeaconSprite-CA-02._V387139546_.png";
   </script>
     <meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="on">
     <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com">
@@ -464,6 +459,7 @@



+    
 <!--btech-iplc-->
   <script type="text/javascript">
```

If you absolutely have to have this as a web service somewhere, you can make a CGI shell script do it, using standard techniques for that sort of thing.